# Get all TextBoxes in a page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Very simple but I can't figure out why it wont works.
I got five `TextBox` and one `Button`, click to count the number of `TextBox`.

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Testing._Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Test"></asp:Label> </br>   
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="40px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="40px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Width="40px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Width="40px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Width="40px"></asp:TextBox>
</br>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Generate" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```

Code behind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var List = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
    Label1.Text = List.Count().ToString();
}
```

But the result return me `0`.

Comment: Probably your `TextBoxes` are inside another container like `div`.

Comment: `this.Page.Form.Controls.OfType<TextBox>`

Comment: @S.Akbari hmm there is no div here

Comment: @BernardWong So can you post your full aspx code?

Comment: What is `this` inside the method? Is it the form, or the button? See @MikeDebela's comment.

Comment: @krillgar Based on the aspx code that posted recently his controls are inside a `ContentPlaceHolder`. So he need to replace `this` with `MainContent` `ContentPlaceHolder` in a way that I pointed in my answer.

Comment: Won't work if text boxes are in a div or table. See my solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `TextBoxes` are inside a `ContentPlaceHolder` so you need to replace the `this` keyword with your `ContentPlaceHolder`(`MainContent`). This should works as you want:

```
var List = (Page.Master.FindControl("MainContent") as ContentPlaceHolder)
            .Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
Label1.Text = List.Count().ToString();
```

Comment: Won't work if text boxes are in a div or table

Comment: @Kim Give your div an id, and set RunatServer to true.

Answer (score 0):

Most solutions will not work if text boxes are in tables or divs. The only way is to recursively look for them in all controls. Paste the following function in a class somewhere.

```
public static List<Control> GetAllControls(List<Control> controls, Type t, Control parent) //first call pass this.Page as the 'Parent' parameter
    {
        foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
        {
            if (c.GetType() == t)
                controls.Add(c);
            if (c.HasControls())
                controls = GetAllControls(controls, t, c);
        }
        return controls;
    }
```

Then from your asp page you call it as follows.

```
List<Control> list = new List<Control>();
list = GetAllControls(list, typeof(TextBox), this.Page);
```

This gets all controls of the type you passed (in my example it was TextBox)

Then you can iterate through the list of Textbox controls.

```
foreach (Control ctl in list)
{
    if (ctl.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))   //this should always test true but you i left it here for clarity     
    {
        //do something  
        ((TextBox)ctl).Attributes.Add("onfocus", "this.select()");
    }
 }
```

Here is my implementation to add the select() attribute to all text boxes.

```
//my asp page
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        Utils.SetTextBoxFocusSelect(this.Page);
}

//in a utilities class
public class Utils
{
    public static void SetTextBoxFocusSelect(Page page)
    {
        List<Control> list = new List<Control>();
        list = GetAllControls(list, typeof(TextBox), page);

        foreach (Control ctl in list)
        {
            if (ctl.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
            {
                ((TextBox)ctl).Attributes.Add("onfocus", "this.select()");
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<Control> GetAllControls(List<Control> controls, Type t, Control parent /* can be Page */)
    {
        foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
        {
            if (c.GetType() == t)
                controls.Add(c);
            if (c.HasControls())
                controls = GetAllControls(controls, t, c);
        }
        return controls;
    }
}
```